# RSA Encryption in .NET core (Differences from .Net Framework)

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core

I need help!
This code works with .Net Framework but it is showing different results with .Net Core 3.1.

```
  public static void RSAPersistKeyInCSP(string ContainerName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a new instance of CspParameters.  Pass
                // 13 to specify a DSA container or 1 to specify
                // an RSA container.  The default is 1.
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(1);

                // Specify the container name using the passed variable.
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate
                //a new key pair.  Pass the CspParameters class to persist the 
                //key in the container.  The PersistKeyInCsp property is true by 
                //default, allowing the key to be persisted. 
                RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                
                //Indicate that the key was persisted.
                Console.WriteLine("The RSA key was persisted in the container, \"{0}\".", ContainerName);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }
        }

static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                //toinclude the public key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                return RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
            //to the console.
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return null;
            }

        }
```

I'm using it like this :

```
RSAPersistKeyInCSP(privateKey);

RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters
{
   Modulus = System.Convert.FromBase64String(strModulo),
   Exponent = System.Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey)
};


byte[] encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSAKeyInfo, false);
```

I could not find out why, but it's returning different results on .NET Framework and .NET CORE.

I did try to change the RSAEncrypt to the code bellow, but it still does not work.

```
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            rsa.KeySize = 1024;
            rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            // when the key next gets used it will be created at that keysize.
            return rsa.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        }
```

Anybody has any advice?

Comment: How are the results different and why is it important that the "results" are equal?

Comment: From your comments: `Pass the CspParameters class to...`. You don't seem to be doing that, though.

Comment: I use this function to communicate with a digital time clock (I don't know if it exists outside Brazil). It requires me to send the data formatted as "encrypted with RSA and encoded in BASE64". The code works with .NetFramework but on .NetCore it does not 
recognizes the encrypted data I'm sending.

Comment: @CezarWagenheimer can you create a complete minimal reproducible app that runs in .net framework giving you the string recognized by API? the code you posted has more to do with Key storage than actual encryption